# parsing from json for faq section

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am doing this faq section by getting content from json files, which I am able to achieve.
But my confusion is how to integrate a "Category" heading for the faq sections ? please share some idea on how to achieve it.

// Script

```
 $.getJSON("faqs.json",function(data){
    $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
    var faqs =
    "<dt>"+data.title+"</dt><dd>"+data.answer+"</dd>";
    $(faqs).appendTo("#faq");
    });
    });
```

// JSON format is

```
{"posts": [ 
{ "title":"Question 1?", "answer":"faq answer 1" }, 
{ "title":"Question 2?", "answer":"faq answer 2" }, 
]}
```

// Current HTML Output

```
<dl id="faq">
<dt>Question 1?</dt><dd>faq answer 1</dd>
<dt>Question 2?</dt><dd>faq answer 2</dd>
</dl>
```

// Expected HTML out should be

```
<dl id="faq">
<strong>Category 1</strong>
<dt>Question 1?</dt><dd>faq answer 1</dd>
<dt>Question 2?</dt><dd>faq answer 2</dd>
<strong>Category 2</strong>
<dt>Question 1?</dt><dd>faq answer 1</dd>
<dt>Question 2?</dt><dd>faq answer 2</dd>
</dl>
```

How do i integrate the "Category" section in JSON file, if so how do i parse into the HTML.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change JSON output to something like:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "title": "Category 1",
      "posts": [ 
        { "title":"Question 1?", "answer":"faq answer 1" }, 
        { "title":"Question 2?", "answer":"faq answer 2" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Category 2",
      "posts": [ 
        { "title":"Question 1?", "answer":"faq answer 1" }, 
        { "title":"Question 2?", "answer":"faq answer 2" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Change script to something like:

```
$.getJSON("faqs.json",function(data) {
  $.each(data.categories, function(i, c) {
    var section = "<strong>" + c.title + "</strong>";
    $.each(c.posts, function(j, p) {
      section += "<dt>" + p.title + "</dt><dd>" + p.answer + "</dd>";
    });
    $(section).appendTo("#faq");
  });
});
```

However, keep in mind that your required output is not valid: the strong tag should not be nested in the dl tag.

[This can be seen in action here](http://jsbin.com/utimi3/5)

Comment: there was a syntax error in line 5 of script code, even after removing it I am getting text as "undefined" in dt dd tags...

Comment: Yes, very true, I apologise for that. I have now corrected the script section above. You can see it working at http://jsbin.com/utimi3/5